# local file system access via HTML5 and PHP5

Tags: php, html, filesystems, client-side

I want to enhance my browser-based web application with functionality that needs to read the absolute path of the files being uploaded and used for some processing, I have used HTML5 File API and [PHP POST Upload method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) to support the upload functionality.

Question: Direct or work around method of reading the absolute path (client-side) of the file that is uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with FileAPI yet, but from what I can see in specs.:

1. For security reasons full file path ain't available
2. FileAPI provides `File` interface that contains `name` attribute. However [according to the spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#file-attrs) it's file name only, without path.

You aren't able to get that.